# Insert negative lookahead when joining multiple re.compile

Tags: python, regex

How do I join a these three `re.compile` into a unified regex, and then use that for a *negative lookahead*? I.e. if there is not a match in string `s`, then: [do something].

```
regex_eur = re.compile(r"\b(Euro)\b|\b(EUR)\b|\b(\€)\b", re.I)
regex_gbp = re.compile(r"\b(Pound)\b|\b(GBP)\b|\b(\£)\b", re.I)
regex_jpy = re.compile(r"\b(Yen)\b|\b(JPY)\b", re.I)
```

My attempt:

```
regex_all = re.compile(r"\b(?:%s)\b" % "|".join([regex_eur, regex_gbp, regex_jpy]))

if not re.search(regex_all, s):
    #Do something
```

Note that this doesn't use negative lookahead, just `if not` which doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure how to append the negative lookahead with `.join` if that is indeed the correct method.

---

**Edit**: Clarification of my objective.

I want to make sure that none of the regex "keywords" are in the string. I.e. none of the following are allowed: "Euro", "EUR", "€", "Pound", "GBP", "£", and so forth.

I have decided to use regex because the word boundaries `\b` are important for the implementation.

Comment: I don't see any lookbehind here. Just one big alternation based regex should work for you

Comment: Regarding the terminology: isn't a negative lookbehind just a lookahead?

Comment: @anderas Sorry, maybe I've misunderstood what a negative lookbehind is. My objective is simply to make sure that none of the regex "keywords" are in the string. I.e. none of the following are allowed: Euro, EUR, €, Pound, GBP, £, and so forth.

Comment: If I've misunderstood the terminology I'll edit the title/question to something better matching the objective.

Comment: Actually you might be right. I just read this term for the first time, and from the python docs, these might really be different :)

Comment: We need some sample input which produces the incorrect output using your code, along with what the correct output would be for that sample input. As is, I don't understand what you want exactly, or what is/isn't working for you.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: The first issue is joining together re.compiles into one. An error I'm getting is `('sequence item 0: expected string, _sre.SRE_Pattern found'`. So it seems like `.join` wants to take list items instead of a list of patterns. The next issue would be how to properly write the "negative" statement, either by including a negative condition into the regex itself, or with a `if not` statement in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for this [negative lookahead regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
regex = re.compile(r"^(?!.*(?:€|£|\b(?:Euro?|Pound|GBP|Yen|JPY)\b))", re.UNICODE | re.I)
```

Which basically will fail the match if any of the above strings are found in the input. Please note that `€` and `£` won't need `\b` (word boundary) because these currency symbols are not considered word characters.

Comment: Thanks, this works! And thanks for the info regarding the currency symbols. Your answer entails creating a new regex from scratch instead of joining the existing compile patterns, but that's not a big deal (and probably the easiest considering that the boundaries shouldn't apply for currency symbols) :)